# I am trying to convert the text file into CSV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert the text file into CSV in Python
The input text file is as follows:

```
Employee Name: Dr.john doe
Designation: Professor
Email: johndoe@google.com
"ContactNo: 1234567, 9999999"
"Qualification: M.Tech., Ph.D."
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security
Employee Name: Dr. john doe2 
Designation: Professor2
Email: johndoe2@google.com
ContactNo: 222222222
"Qualification: B.Tech., Ph.D."
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security2
Employee Name: Dr. john doe3 
Designation: Associate Professor3
Email: johndoe3@google.com
"ContactNo: 333333,4444444"
Qualification: Ph.D.
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security3
Designation: Associate Professor4
Email: johndoe4@google.com
"ContactNo: 44444444 ,Intercom No.44444"
Qualification: : M.Sc. 
Designation: Programmer
Email: johndoe5@google.com
"ContactNo: 5555555555 ,Intercom No.5555"
Qualification: Ph.D |Computer Science
Designation: Computer Operator
Email: johndoe6@google.com
ContactNo: 666666666
"Qualification: D.C.Sc. & E.,"
Designation: Computer Operator
Email: johndoe7@google.com
"ContactNo: 777777777 ,Intercom No.77777<"
"Qualification: D.E & TC.,"
Designation: Instructor4
Email: johndoe8@google.com
"ContactNo: 8888888888 ,Intercom No.8888"
"Qualification: D.C.Sc. & E.,"`
```

I need it in CSV in following format(As you can see only one of the multiple values for a field can be taken and there are some data without the employee name which needs to be excluded in the output CSV file):

```
name,designation,email,contact,Qualification,Specialisation 

Dr. john doe,Professor,johndoe@google.com,1234567,B.E.,network security

Dr. john doe2,Professor,johndoe2@google.com,222222222,M.S.,network security2

Dr. john doe3,Associate,Professor3,johndoe3@gmail.com,333333,M.Tech.,network security3
```

**i have tried various ways but i'm not able to do it(i'm quite new to programming):

using other's examples i've tried this, but i think my question requires a different approach:

```py
records = """Employee Name: Dr. john doe
Designation: Professor
Email: johndoe@google.com
ContactNo: 1234567, 9999999
Qualification: M.Tech., Ph.D.
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security"""

for record in records.split('Employee Name'):
    fields = record.split('\n')
    Employee_Name = "NA"
    Designation = "NA"
    ContactNo = "NA"
    Qualification = "NA"
    Specialization = "NA"
    for field in fields:
        field_name, field_value = field.split(':')
        if field_name == "": # This is employee name, since we split on it
            Employee_Name = field_value
        if field_name == "Designation":
            Designation = field_value
        if field_name == "ContactNo":
            ContactNo = field_value
        if field_name == "Qualification":
            Qualification = field_value
        if field_name == "Specialization":
            Specialization = field_value
```

this is my first question here so kindly ignore any formatting mistakes in the question (PLEASE DONT hold the question if something is improper,i'll update it immediately)

Comment: Hi and welcome, could you post your code, so we can examine which parts of your code don't work. (BTW: your expected output is not regular CSV, because there are no **c**omma-**s**eparated-**v**alues)

Comment: It is good that you have given us expected results; however, can you also mention the actual results you are getting?

Comment: @Quelklef thank you for pointing it out. i'll update it within a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add print statements at various places in your code, you'll find that sometimes `record=''` and sometimes `field=''`.

Add a couple of lines:

```
for record in records.split('Employee Name'):
    if record == '':
        continue
    fields = record.split('\n')
```

and

```
for field in fields:
    if field == '':
        continue
    field_name, field_value = field.split(':')
```

This should now run successfully.

Comment: How can I save the output it in a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
Employee Name: Dr.john doe
Designation: Professor
Email: johndoe@google.com
"ContactNo: 1234567, 9999999"
"Qualification: M.Tech., Ph.D."
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security
Employee Name: Dr. john doe2 
Designation: Professor2
Email: johndoe2@google.com
ContactNo: 222222222
"Qualification: B.Tech., Ph.D."
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security2
Employee Name: Dr. john doe3 
Designation: Associate Professor3
Email: johndoe3@google.com
"ContactNo: 333333,4444444"
Qualification: Ph.D.
Area of Interest / Specialisation: network security3
```

Here is **simple method** which is also applicable if there are many columns ***(No need to write code for each and every field)***

**Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd
tdf = pd.read_csv("D:/emp.txt",sep='\n',doublequote=False, header= None)

tdf = tdf[0].str.split(':', expand=True)

dd = tdf.groupby(0)[1].apply(lambda g: g.values.tolist()).to_dict()

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd)

# If you want to re-arrange the columns (Optional)
df = df[['Employee Name','Designation','Email','ContactNo','Qualification','Area of Interest / Specialisation']]

df.to_csv('D:/EMP.csv',index=False) #Save results in CSV format

df

     Employee Name            Designation                 Email          ContactNo    Qualification Area of Interest / Specialisation
0      Dr.john doe              Professor    johndoe@google.com   1234567, 9999999   M.Tech., Ph.D.                  network security
1   Dr. john doe2              Professor2   johndoe2@google.com          222222222   B.Tech., Ph.D.                 network security2
2   Dr. john doe3    Associate Professor3   johndoe3@google.com     333333,4444444            Ph.D.                 network security3
```